# running command before other finished in python

Tags: python, scripting, python-multiprocessing

I asked already and few people gave good advises but there were to many unknowns for me as I am beginner. Therefore I decided to ask for help again without giving bad code.

I need a script which will execute copy files to directory while the other is still running. 
Basically I run first command, it generates files (until user press enter) and then those files are gone (automatically removed).
What I would like to have is to copying those files (without have to press "Enter" as well). 
I made in bash however I would like to achieve this on python. Please see below:

```
while kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null;do
cp -v /tmp/directory/* /tmp/
done
```

Comment: Look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) modules.

Comment: So first script generates files in a directory, and you want a second script to move the files in another directory, both script running in parallel. Right ? But I have one question : how second script can know that the first one has finished to process a file ? Or is is harmless that second moves a file while first is processing it ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, it is harmless. First script when finish generating files is waiting actually to copy them with "press enter when you finish copying." and then removes them. I want just to do automatically without need to copy/move them and press enter to finish each time.

Comment: Is first *script* a Command Line Interface or a Graphic User Interface script ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is pure command line. In shell you can workaround this "press enter" with "&" and move process to the background. I tried this with os.system but no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If first script is purely command line : it should be fully manageable with a python script.

General architecture :

- python scripts starts first one with `subprocess` module
- reads output from first script until it gets the message asking for pressing enter
- copies all files from source directory to destination directory
- sends `\r` into first script input
- waits first script terminates
- exits

General requirements :

- first script must be purely CLI one
- first script must write to standart output/error and read from standard input - if it reads/writes to *physical* terminal (`/dev/tty` on Unix/Linux or `con:` on Dos/Windows), it **won't work**
- the end of processing **must** be identifiable in standard output/error
- if the two above requirement were no met, the only way would be to wait a define amount of time

Optional operation :

- if there are other interactions in first script (read and/or write), it will be necessary to add the redirections in the script, it is certainly feasible, but will be a little harder

Configuration :

- the command to be run
- the string (from command output) that indicates first program has finished processing
- the source directory
- the destination directory
- a *pattern* for file name to be copied
- if time defined and no identifiable string in output : the delay to wait before copying

A script like that should be simple to write and test and able to manage the first script as you want.

Edit : here is an example of such a script, still without timeout management.

```
import subprocess
import os
import shutil
import re

# default values for command execution - to be configured at installation
defCommand = "test.bat"
defEnd = "Appuyez"
defSource = "."
defDest = ".."
# BEWARE : pattern is in regex format !
defPattern="x.*\.txt"

class Launcher(object):
    '''
Helper to launch a command, wait for a defined string from stderr or stdout
of the command, copy files from a source folder to a destination folder,
and write a newline to the stdin of the command.
Limits : use blocking IO without timeout'''
    def __init__(self, command=defCommand, end=defEnd, source=defSource,
                 dest=defDest, pattern = defPattern):
        self.command = command
        self.end = end
        self.source = source
        self.dest = dest
        self.pattern = pattern

    def start(self):
        'Actualy starts the command and copies the files'
        found = False
        pipes = os.pipe() # use explicit pipes to mix stdout and stderr
        rx = re.compile(self.pattern)
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(self.command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stdout=pipes[1], stderr=pipes[1])
        os.close(pipes[1])
        while True:
            txt = os.read(pipes[0], 1024)
            #print(txt) # for debug
            if str(txt).find(self.end) != -1:
                found = True
                break
        # only try to copy files if end string found
        if found:
            for file in os.listdir(self.source):
                if rx.match(file):
                    shutil.copy(os.path.join(self.source, file), self.dest)
                    print("Copied : %s" % (file,))
            # copy done : write the newline to command input
            cmd.stdin.write(b"\n")
        cmd.stdin.close()
        try:
            cmd.wait()
            print("Command terminated with %d status" % (cmd.returncode,))
        except:
            print("Calling terminate ...")
            cmd.terminate()
        os.close(pipes[0])

# allows to use the file either as an imported module or directly as a script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse optional parameters
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Launch a command and copy files')
    parser.add_argument('--command', '-c', nargs = 1, default = defCommand,
                        help="full text of the command to launch")
    parser.add_argument('--endString', '-e', nargs = 1, default = defEnd,
                        dest="end",
                        help="string that denotes that command has finished processing")
    parser.add_argument('--source', '-s', nargs = 1, default = defSource,
                        help="source folder")
    parser.add_argument('--dest', '-d', nargs = 1, default = defDest,
                        help = "destination folder")
    parser.add_argument('--pattern', '-p', nargs = 1, default = defPattern,
                        help = "pattern (regex format) for files to be copied")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # create and start a Launcher ...
    launcher = Launcher(args.command, args.end, args.source, args.dest,
                        args.pattern)
    launcher.start()
```

Comment: There is a progress bar and when its finished it is awaiting to press enter - during that time, you can copy files to another location. 

I dont really know how to "emulate enter". In bash there is not problem, it will just skip by itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you do not give a clear description of the problem I won't be able to help you. What exists, what is modifiable or not, and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: OK, sorry for not being clear enough. 

1. First command generating files olear1.txt under /tmp/.

The progress bar is showing progress. when its finished, reached 100%. We see /tmp/olear1.txt exists. However after progress bar script(who generates) is waiting with: Press enter to finish and then delete files from /tmp/. 

We can copy / move files from /tmp during that time while its waiting to press enter and its harmless. However its always need to be pressed Enter by user at the end to finish script.

Comment: I would like to copy those files to another directory and after that "Enter" pressed by itself. I want to put all those task together into one script

Comment: Can you remove the *Press enter to finish* and the removal of files from first script ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it cant be done. The first script cannot be modified in any way.

Comment: @olear: I've edited my post with a general architecture. Remaining questions : can the I/O from command be redirected and is the end of processing identifiable in output ?

Comment: Yes I/O can be redirected and the end of processing can be determine in output. Basically if we redirect output from command and get "Press Enter". Files are ready to be copied. After "Press Enter" you get another message - files are deleted. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @olear: If it is Ok for you, could you accept the answer to notify other readers that you no longer need help on this question ? Or do you still need help for writing the python script ?

Comment: It would be great if you could help me to write that script.

Comment: @olear : Fine, but now, think back about what you said in initial question, and the way I described what should be done ... And try to give more relevant details in you next question :-)

Comment: of course will do. I dont understand only argparse and what influence it has on rest of the code. I thought thats used for description / help only.

Comment: @olear : argparse allows to do runtime customisation by allowing optional parameters for the script, if you want to use it for another pair of source-destination directory (and same command), you could use `python script.py --source other_src_dir --dest other_dest_dir`. Try `python script.py --help` ...

Comment: I understand that part. However if I do not want to give that option and do not include even that module argsparse. How can I make those default values for not being depended on args. Every time I get error that name hasn't been defined. However I can see them in first method.

Comment: Figured out that eventually :) once again thank you.